# Issue with import path in Python 3

Tags: python, python-import

I'm having an issue with the import statement in Python 3. I'm following a book (Python 3 Object Oriented) and am having the following structure:

```
parent_directory/
       main.py
       ecommerce/
             __init__.py
             database.py
             products.py
             payments/
                    __init__.py
                    paypal.py
                    authorizenet.py
```

In paypal.py, I'm trying to use the Database class from database.py. So I tried this:

```
from ecommerce.database import Database
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'ecommerce'
```

so I try with both of these import statements:

```
from .ecommerce.database import Database

from ..ecommerce.database import Database
```

and I get this error:

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your `parent_directory`to Python's search path. For example so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/full/path/to/parent_directory')
```

Alternatively, you can add `parent_directory` to the environmental variable `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: This means that if I want to move my parent_directory somewhere else or if I want to distribute the 'ecommerce' folder as a package, it won't work, right? Any other ways to import a class located in a parent directory?

Comment: Usually, if you distribute, i.e. people use `pip` to install, your package ends up in `site-packages`, which is in the PYTHONPATH by default. For development just make a directory `dev` or such, put it on the PYTHONPATH once and put all your projects in there.